# Access VBA to open/activate a database table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an open MS Access database with 20 tables showing in the left and two tabs open showing the contents of two tables. I am trying to write vba code to 1) select/activate one of the tabs that is already open, and 2) to open a new tab for one of the tables on the left that is not yet open.

I've looked at many examples, but they all talk about Forms, not the tab control/tabs that I want to work with in the main Access table display. Here's my code so far - I can get the name of the table, but I can't figure out how to open and activate a tab for the table in the Access display.

```
Sub ActivateCommandsTable()
 ' activate or open a tab for the Commands table
 Dim tbl As AccessObject, db As Object
 Set db = Application.CurrentData

 ' Search for open AccessObject objects in AllTables collection.
 For Each tbl In db.AllTables

 If tbl.IsLoaded = True Then
    ' Print name of the table
    Debug.Print tbl.name
    If tbl.name = "Commands" Then

        ' I need some code here to activate/open the table tab

        Exit Sub
    End If
 End If

 Next tbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DoCmd.OpenTable`.

`DoCmd.OpenTable tbl.Name`